# Логика условия PHP

Tags: php

## Задача:

#### Нужно отправлять 5 запросов (не более 3-ех одновременно!)

Для этого сделал 2 условия

```
// Узнаем текущее время для того что бы записать его в базу
$sms_date = current_time('mysql');


// Получаем время из базы в переменную для того чтобы в дальнейшем сравнить время
$get_date_sms = get_option('sms_stat_all_date');
$get_date_sms_balance = get_option('sms_balance_all_date');

// К времени полученному из базы добавляем 2 минуты 
$get_date_sms = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 minute", strtotime($get_date_sms)));


// К времени полученному из базы добавляем 4 минуты 
$get_date_sms_balance = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+4 minute", strtotime($get_date_sms_balance)));

// Выполняем проверку #1
if( $sms_date >= $get_date_sms ){

    //echo "Если условие выполнилось то шлем запрос и обновляем информацию в базе<br><hr>";
    update_option( 'sms_stat_month', $month_sms_stat );
    update_option( 'sms_stat_week', $week_sms_stat );
    update_option( 'sms_stat_today', $today_sms_stat );

    //echo "Если условие выполнилось то записываем время в базу при обновлении сайта<hr>";
    update_option( 'sms_stat_all_date', $sms_date );


}

// Выполняем проверку #2
if( $sms_date >= $get_date_sms_balance ){

    //echo "Если условие выполнилось то шлем запрос и обновляем информацию в базе<br><hr>";
    update_option( 'sms_stat_all', $all_sms_stat );
    update_option( 'sms_balance', $sms_balance );

    //echo "Если условие выполнилось то записываем время в базу при обновлении сайта<hr>";
    update_option( 'sms_balance_all_date', $sms_date );
}
```

1 условие если прошло 2 минуты (отправлять запросы)

2 условие если прошло 4 минуты (отправлять запросы)

## Проходит 5 минут

И выполняются 2 условия одновременно как написать правильную логику?

Comment: а что за заданное время? чо там

Comment: @Manitikyl, предполагаю, что эта переменная обновляется вытекая из условий выше своего.

Comment: мне кажется там наоборот константа, например в заданном времени 00:00, а в текущем как раз 00:02 и 00:04, собсна отсюда и косяки.

Comment: тогда не понятно как вообще это работает.

Comment: Добавьте к условию `elseif` - всегда будет выполняться какое-то одно из условий, но не оба сразу.

Comment: ну я так понимаю, что если прошло 6 минут должно выполнится 2?, может есть смысл в каждом `if` вычитать кол-во минут из времени, тогда более логично будет

Comment: @Эдуард Обновил код выше

Comment: @Manitikyl Обновил код выше

Comment: Так а что вы хотите после истечения 5 минут? и первое и второе выполняется это логично, ибо от первого прошло 2 минуты и от второго 4. вы хотите чтобы 2 запроса выполнилось если прошло 6 минут?

Comment: @Manitikyl Да я хочу чтобы 2 запроса выполнилось, но проблема в том что можно отправить только 3 одинаковых запроса за 1 минуту, а тут одинаковых запросов 4, и один запрос возвращает ошибку. Помоги пожалуйста =)

Comment: что за 3 одинаковых запроса за одну минуту? откуда они взялись. Давайте так: напишите конкретно что и как должно выполняться: пример: если 5 минут: то только запросы во втором ифе, если 6 минут: то запросы в двух ифах и т.д.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81498/discussion-between---and-manitikyl).

Comment: воспользуйтесь кроном.

Answer (score 0):

```
`$sms_date >= $get_date_sms`
```

- некорректное сравнение величин - вы сравниваете строки что не допустимо. Рекомендую сравнивать UNIX time формат, его возвращает strtotime()
если вам нужны задержки в выполнении скрипта - используйте функцию

`sleep();`